# PCB Adapter for different signals

Tags: adapter

I need to use a connector that only exists in a version for PCB installation, but I have to connect it to a cable; so, I was thinking of making a small adapter PCB on which to directly solder the wires.

Now my problem is that I have to create this adapter PCB for various cables, which are all different: some are CAT5 and CAT6 Ethernet, some are LVDS signals, others are single wire signals, etc etc all with different pinouts; and I would like to make a single generic adapter that works for everyone.

My question is, since the PCB will only be a few centimeters, maximum 4 or 5 cm, can I use all straight traces not considering the differential pairs? For example, if I have an ethernet signal with differential pairs at 100ohm, if I have a piece of 4 or 5 cm in which I only have single ended traces, can I have problems?

If so, I would have all single ended tracks, and since I don't have a ground plane, I can't control the impedance of the tracks. What track size should I use to have as few problems as possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What connector is this? If it's designed for board-to-board connections, it may not be the best choice for a cable-mount connector.

Comment: Why not use a ground plane and impedance match everything so that you're sure it will be ok?

Comment: @user1850479 if the PCB is a 2-layer 1.6mm FR4 then you may end up with ridiculously wide traces for the required diff impedance. For such a simple board 4-layer (or more) would be overkill.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Unless he is doing this at home, the cost of a 4 layer, controlled impedance board this small is maybe 2 or 3 dollars extra for 5 or 10 boards.  I think that is worthwhile if routing LVDS.

Comment: @Hearth: This one: https://b2b.harting.com/ebusiness/it/har-bus-HM-Federl-Typ-P0-m-Schirmbl/17250951102?newPDP=true

Comment: @user1850479: I can also put a ground plane, but what do I connect it to? For example, in the case of the ethernet cable I only have 4 differential pairs, what do I connect the ground to? It would just be a ground layer not connected to anything, is that still ok for impedance control purposes?

Comment: In the ethernet case you do not (necessarily) need a ground plane (see your previous question).  You probably do need it for the LVDS though, which is going to be less forgiving than ethernet, possibly a lot less forgiving.

Comment: @user1850479: Yes, I've done this before with ethernet and I have no problems. But with the LVDS I have the exact same situation, the cable only has twisted pairs, what do I connect the ground plane to?

Comment: Usually LVDS has a ground on the connector which you would tie to the plane. If it doesn't then you could route it like Ethernet and get the target impedance by coupling the two signal lines with no ground.